# I got caught cheating on an online exam and I feel so guilty. What do I do?

Tags: ethics, exams, cheating

**What happened:**

I got caught cheating on an online exam consisting of 25 multiple-choice questions and a written part of my exam worth 55/80 marks. I had access to a one-page cheat sheet, but I still went to another website to double-check a few of my multiple-choice questions. However, I didn't cheat on my written answers.

I think deep down, I felt guilty, but I repressed my memories of what happened when I cheated on the exam to the point where I even forgot I cheated. It didn't help that I have a bunch of mental illnesses I had to deal with: depression, anxiety, ADHD, autism.

When I first got an email, I thought it was the wording of my written answers, but then it turned out there were screenshots of me accessing the website. At that time, I got an anxiety attack and I denied it by trying to show the reasoning behind my answers.

**When I met with my teacher:**

A few days later I went to the meeting with some stuff prepared and my cheat sheet, but then the evidence of the screenshots was there and I panicked. I got an anxiety attack in front of my professor. I didn't know what to do and felt like the world was ending. At that moment, I denied it and tried explaining my side of the story, saying that there were technical difficulties and I had trouble with my exam, causing me to get logged out. Those technical difficulties happened, but I think the memories returned at that point, making me feel even worse. I didn't know how to explain that I felt guilty, and I felt like I would get expelled or suspended. I already struggle with talking to people on a daily basis. Worse, the incident would be on my transcript and record.

**I admitted that I cheated and took accountability:**

After the meeting, I had time to reflect and I emailed my professor about how I wanted to own up to what I did so that it never happens again (I finally admitted to what happened), and how I wanted someone with me in the exam at all times. My professor decided to give me a 25% deduction, which I am extremely grateful for, but I'm still really anxious about if it would appear on my transcript. I guess it's a consequence I can never forget.

I'm planning on transferring to a university since I'm currently in college, which is why I'm so scared about this being on my record. What if the university doesn't accept me because I cheated once in the past? Plus, I'm not sure how to move forward. I feel like a horrible person because I have to live with this mistake. I really want to take accountability and move forward, but I don't know how. It also sucks because I was never taught how to study and usually relied on pure memorization. I want to be a better person, but I feel like I never can because of what I did.

What do I do? How can I move forward and ensure this doesn't happen again? I don't want to succumb to the temptation of cheating or to my impulses again.

**edit:** For clarification, this was the first time I cheated. I never cheated in high school, and I always make sure that my citations are correct so I don't accidentally plagiarize. But I always felt so overwhelmed to be perfect because I had expectations from others to fulfill. I'm not as strict with it as I was in high school, but I'm still recovering from the mental burnout and the negative effects it caused me. I feel like even if I got away with it, I don't know if I can even keep this secret. Over time, I know that the guilt will fester, and I'll end up confessing to a friend or my parents about it.

I feel like my mind is a jumbled mess. I feel regretful for forgetting that I cheated and denying the accusation out of panic. I want to die of shame and embarrassment because I know what I did was wrong. I will talk to a therapist about this, but I feel like I'm a humiliation, like I'm a disgrace. I hate myself so much for this. I cried myself to sleep, and I feel like I can't even function as a proper human being.

I already sent a thank you email to my professor, but I'm planning on sending a reflection letter because I feel like I need to show that I want to improve myself.

Comment: With depression, anxiety e.t.c. do you have a mental health professional that you see regularly? I am not sure if this is something to be answered quickly in an online forum. However, I do think that you feeling guilty about this shows that you are a good person, trying to do their best.

Comment: It seems you're not sorry you cheated, but you're sorry you got caught. was this the first time you ever cheated? How many times have you removed cheating cases from memory? I think your professor was kind enough to let you go, it won't be on the transcript.

Comment: This was the first time I ever cheated. And even if I got away with it, I think the guilt would eat me up either way. I have trouble keeping secrets of what I did when it comes to lying, and the longer I keep it, the more horrible I feel. I don't know what to do to show that I've learned from my mistake and that I want to take accountability

Comment: You're providing a very inconsistent story. In your original question, by your own admission, you wouldn't remember all the times you've cheated. Your comment indicates otherwise. By the sounds of the situation, it seems more likely you've cheated in other ways, but may not necessarily believe your actions constitute cheating. Your question indicates denial (lying) as your initial response, so an immediate denial again appears to be part of a pattern. I don't believe you're lying now, however, given you've listed a few mental health concerns, I hope you seek professional help for that.

Comment: Thanks, I plan on talking about this to a therapist because I don't want this to happen again. I feel ashamed that I even cheated in an exam by searching outside sources and that it's the worst mistake I have ever made. I don't know how to forgive myself and move forward.

Comment: When faced with a major emotional crisis, I really don't think that "ask for advice from strangers on the public Internet" is a very wise strategy.  You say "I plan on talking about this to a therapist" so I would suggest you do that *first*.  Preferably *before* you read any responses to your Internet posts.  From what you are describing, it sounds urgent.

Answer (score 3):

In order to ensure that you don't cheat again, I suggest you think why do you cheat on exams.

If it is because you are not sufficiently prepared for the exam, then the best course of action is to plan your studying, not overload on classes, and commit to the classes you are currently taking.

If it is because you are feeling anxious or depressed, I suggest seeking professional help to deal with those issues, which likely affect you in more ways than just how you handle yourself in classes.

Another point I will mention is that there is no shame in doing poorly in a class. Students often breeze through high-school where things were easy for them, and then receive a rude awakening in college. Accept that you are learning difficult things now, and that you won't be perfect. I got a C in calculus 101 and it's the grade I'm most proud of, went on to do a PhD in math. When you retake a class you get to learn stuff better, and understand course expectations more. I have a lot of respect for students who overcome adversity, and this is something that graduate admission committees do look at (e.g. a student who did poorly on their first year and then moved on to do really well on their last couple of years may actually scan positively for some).

Comment: Thank you so much - now that I think about it, the reason why I cheated was because I felt overwhelmed with the expectations of being "perfect".  I remember feeling so guilty right after I cheated though. I'll most likely learn and try to access resources to help me through this. I don't know how I'll be able to forgive myself though.

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer: I am not a therapist nor a school counselor. This is just my opinion. Take it with a grain of salt.**

It seems like you are showing genuine remorse for what you did. That's a good sign. You should be very thankful to this professor. Typically, cheating means expulsion and/or a grade of F in the class. While I don't condone what you did, I do understand the insane pressure to do well. Perhaps it is time to do some soul searching and think why you are pursuing a college degree. Is it because you want to please your parents or because you want to better yourself? Although the first reason may indeed push you to greater heights, it will inevitably catch up with you at a point where you are burnt-out and fed up with it all. It is not sustainable motivation. If that's the case (which is my guess), then at least find an academic track that you like doing. I started as a pre-med student in undergrad, so that I would be the first MD in the family. But after some rather regretful accidents in the chemistry lab (I had to pay $10 dollars for a broken pipette) and some low scores in human anatomy, I soon realized that it wasn't for me. I didn't want to force it anymore and went my own way with a mathematics specialization, without caring what my parents thought.

Also, while I do get the anxiety and mental health concerns, do realize that poor mental health and anxiety are NOT excuses for poor behavior. If you suffer from mental health issues, follow up with your therapist (which you seem to be doing already). I am not a PhD in psychology, but this sounds an awful lot like obsessive-compulsive disorder (OCD) or the like. What stands out to me is the suddenly cheating without remembering (a compulsion) in response to a trigger to double-check (an obsession). Now you feel lots of shame and guilt directed at yourself. Let's say for argument's sake that you do have OCD. The treatment for that is exposure-response-prevention (erp) therapy and being able to sit with the discomfort of uncertainty about your future (since you express concerns with it being in your record). In that case, you would want to gradually expose yourself to triggering situations, such as interacting with the professor. It isn't an easy thing to treat, but it can be done. But again, this is just a hypothetical scenario, not actual medical advice.

Again, I get that mental health issues make studying much more difficult than what it needs to be. I would have a conversation with your therapist and ask if he or she can provide a letter to request special accommodations. This is only to level the playing field and can give you assistance when taking quizzes or exams. There is no shame in using these if you need them. Sometimes a matter of extra time can make a lot of difference. I wish you all the best.